# How to keep track of the files I read into a database in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, mariadb

### Situation

I get a ton of json files from a remote data source. I organize these files into an archive, then read them into a database. The archive exists to rebuild the database, if necessary.

The json files are generated remotely and sent to my server periodically and the reading-in process happens continuously. One more than one occasion, we had a power loss to our severs overnight or over the weekend, this was a huge problem for database loading, since the processes halted and I didn't know what had been loaded and what hadn't so I had to roll back to some previously known state and rebuild out of the archive.

To fix this problem, my master loader daemon (written in python) now uses the `logging` package to track what files it has loaded. The basic workflow of the loader daemon is

- `cp` json file to archive
- `rm' original
- insert archived copy to database (its MariaDB)
- commit to database
- log filename of loaded json file

I'm not so much worried about duplicates in the database, but I don't want gaps; that is, things in the archive that are not in the database. This methods has so far and seems guaranteed to prevent any gaps.

For my logging, it basically looks like this. When the daemon starts up on a set of received files' names, it checks for duplicates that have already been loaded to the destination database and then loads all the non-duplicates. It is possible to get duplicates from my remote data source.

```
def initialize_logs(filenames, destination)
   try:
      with open("/data/dblogs/{0}.log".format(destination), 'r') as already_used:
         seen = set([line.rstrip("\n") for line in already_used])
   except FileNotFoundError:
      print("Log file for {0} not found. Repair database".format(destination))
      quit()

   fnamelog = logging.getLogger('filename.log')
   fnamelog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   fh = logging.FileHandler("/data/dblogs/{0}.log".format(destination))
   fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   fnamelog.addHandler(fh)
```

Then, as I process the jsonfiles, I log each file added using

```
fnamelog.info(filename)
```

The database loader is run parallelized, so I originally chose the `logging` package for its built in concurrency protections. There are a variety of databases; not every database pulls all data from the json files. Some databases with more information are shorter in time, usually one to two months. In this case, it is nice to have a log file with all json files in a given database, so if I want to add some on to it, I don't have to worry about what is already in there, the log file is keeping track.

---

### Problem

A year has passed. I have kept getting json files. I am now getting around a million files per month. The text logging of each filename as it is processed in is clumsy, but it still works...for now. There are multiple databases, but for the largest ones, the log file is over half a GB. I feel like this logging solution will not work well for much longer.

**What options are available in python to track which filenames have been inserted into a database, when there are over 10 million filenames per database, and rising?**

Comment: Do your filenames have ordering and unique names? Maybe it would be sufficient to remember the name of the last file successfully imported?

Comment: @Kos They have unique names and are ordered by timestamp. Unfortunately, due to connection issues from the remote site, they often arrive out of order; or not at all and they have to be manually moved.

Comment: So maybe you could remember the last file with the property that this file and all files before this one have been successfully imported with no gaps? Updating would be a bit trickier but it might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to log the files in a table in the database itself rather than in a text log file. If you added some columns for things like import date or file name, that might provide you a little bit of flexibility with respect to finding information from these logs when you need to do that, but also it would allow you to perform periodic maintenance (like for example deleting log records that are more than a few months old if you know you won't need to look at those ever).

If you decide to keep using text based log files, you might consider breaking them up so you don't wind up with a giant monolithic log file. When you install things like Apache that log lots of data, you'll see it automatic sets up [log rotation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to compress and archive log files periodically...

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what type of database you are using but the general approach to take is

1) make a hash of each json file.  SHA256 is widely available.  If you are concerned about performance see this post https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

2) make the hash field a unique key on your database and before you do the other operations try and insert it.  If you can't the record already exists and the transaction will abort

Comment: It is MariaDB. It looks like a section in the question wasn't formatted properly.

Comment: I was thinking this over some more, the unique key idea has some merit. Is there any reason to use a hash of each json file instead of just using its filename in the database? I don't really have any security concerns with this system.

Comment: As long as you are absolutely certain that the data being fed in to make the hash (the filename or the whole file ) is unique, either is fine

Answer (score 0):

Program 1:

```
Foreach file in input directory
    INSERT IGNORE into database the MD5 of the file
    "mv" the file to the archive directory
```

Program 2, a "keep-alive" program.

It is run via `cron` every minute and tries to launch Program 1, but don't start it if it is already running.

Notes:

- 'mv' and 'cron' assume Unix.  If using Windows, do the equivalent.
- 'mv' is atomic, so the file will be either in one directory of the other; no hassle of knowing whether it is 'processed'.  (So, I wonder why you even have a database table??)
- Since the `INSERT` and `mv` cannot realistically be done "atomically", here is why my plan is safe:  `IGNORE`.
- The "is it running" can be handled in a number of ways, either in Program 1 or 2.
- You could add a timestamp and/or filename to the table containing the md5; whatever you like.
- Since it is not a good idea to have even 10K files in a directory, you *should* use something other than the pair of flat directories I have envisioned.

You are getting only about 1 file every 3 seconds.  This is not a heavy load unless the files are huge.  Then it becomes an I/O problem, not a database problem.

I have a feeling that either I am missing a hidden 'requirement', or you are being extra paranoid.  I don't really understand what you need to do with the files.